# how to test application deployed in websphere cluster.?

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing, websphere-6.1

I have create a cluster in `websphere` and deployed a `defaultapplication` coming with ibm package to cluster.
Now,i want to test this application to check weather it installed correctly on each member of the cluster or not.
`How can i check that on which port it is running` i have tried with default port but i fail not get that.
i have installed websphere in machine that have `Windows OS`.

Thanks in advanced.

**Edited:-**  
i want to ope application that deployed in the cluster, how can i open it??
any idea about this..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [`WC_defaulthost`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rmig_portnumber.html) port for each of the cluster members. You can find these [ports](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rendpoint.html) in the WebSphere Integrated Solutions Console in WAS 6.1 at *Servers* > *Application Servers* > *[serverName]* > *Communications* > *Ports*.

Comment: that's right but i want to access application that is deployed on cluster, how can i open that application in browser??

Comment: In a clustered environment, the application is deployed on each individual application server, so you should be able to navigate to each individual cluster member to view the app instance running on that server: http://<hostname>:<WC_defaulthost>/<contextroot>/<appresource>.

Comment: Thanks i have checked it individual it is running. How can point the whole cluster with one common address??

Comment: You will need to add an additional process, such as an HTTP server, ODR, etc. to sit in front of the cluster and route requests accordingly to the cluster members.